# TextInput underline color for ios in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, underline

i am doing mobile applications in react-native for android and ios.
In my project i am using TextInput Component(ios). This component appear without underline. How to use TextInput with underline color in ios.

code sample -

```
<TextInput
 ref={'cardbatch1'}                 
 keyboardType = 'numeric'
 placeholder = 'Batch Number'
 autoCapitalize = 'none'                                                    
/>
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could add borderBottomWidth and borderBottomColor to TextInput or simply draw a view with 1 or 2 px height below TextInput.

Comment: Thanks..I will go with borderBottomWidth and borderBottomColor.

Comment: This is not working in android. How to make in android

Comment: On Android use: `underlineColorAndroid="transparent"`

Answer (score 6):

Try this in styles.. see the difference in output

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    inputBox: {
        .....
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: 'gray',
        ....
    }
});
```

Finally add the style in textInput

```
<TextInput
 ...             
 keyboardType = 'numeric'
 placeholder = 'Batch Number'
 autoCapitalize = 'none'
 style={styles.inputBox}
.....                                                    
/>
```